# Sphinx Search result gives 0 matches

Tags: sphinx, java

I have total 720 sphinx index with 1.21 GB size. Here attached all index with one service. it takes 800MB of RAM. I have used sql_attr_str2ordinal for storing string so RAM is reduced and now it takes 17MB only. but the problem here is the search result give 0 matches.Search is applied using java api from sphinx index.
Conf file and java code are as following:

```
searchd{    
 listen         = 516   
 log                =    D:\programs\spinx\spinxexperiment\project\log\searchd.log
query_log       = D:\programs\spinx\spinxexperiment\project\log\query.log
read_timeout    = 5
max_children    = 30
pid_file        = D:\programs\spinx\spinxexperiment\project\log\searchd.pid
max_matches     = 1000
seamless_rotate = 0
preopen_indexes = 0
unlink_old      = 1
ondisk_dict_default = 1
mva_updates_pool   = 1M
workers         = threads # for RT to work}

source webusagedatagroup20120301{
type            = pgsql
    sql_host        = 127.0.0.1
    sql_user        = postgres
sql_pass        = 
sql_db          = iviewdb
sql_port        = 5432
sql_query       = SELECT id,username as username_ord,domain as  domain_ord,application,hits,bytes from webusagedata1        
sql_attr_str2ordinal    = username_ord
sql_attr_str2ordinal    = domain_ord
sql_attr_str2ordinal    = application
sql_attr_bigint     = hits
sql_attr_bigint     = bytes}

  index webusagedatagroup20120301{
source  = webusagedatagroup20120301
path    = D:\programs\spinx\spinxexperiment\project\data\20120301\group\webusagedatagroup20120301
preopen         = 0
docinfo         = inline
ondisk_dict     = 1
charset_type        = sbcs
rt_field        = username
rt_field        = domain
rt_field        = application
rt_attr_bigint      = hits
rt_attr_bigint      = bytes}
```

**code:**

```
client = new SphinxClient("127.0.0.1",516);         
client.SetMatchMode(SphinxClient.SPH_MATCH_PHRASE);
query=prepareQuery();
client.SetLimits(0, 20);            
client.SetMaxQueryTime(0);
client.SetConnectTimeout(60000);
client.SetSelect("*, SUM(bytes) as bytes_total");           
client.SetGroupBy("application", SphinxClient.SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR,"username asc");
SphinxResult res = client.Query("divyesh.modi", "webusagedatagroup20120130");
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed over on the sphinx forum. A index needs a field(s) to work. Your index has no fields, so will be ineffective.

As you seem to want to be able to search by username, need to make the username both a field AND a ordinaal attribute (so you can do group by without having to use string attributes)

You need to note the columns twice in sql_query, once for the field, once for the attribute.

Comment: when I use sql_field_string it gives error during creating an index beacuse i have used docinfo as an 'inline'.

Comment: don't use sql_field_string then! You've already decided NOT to use string attributes I thought.